# Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial Chapter 8 sign-in

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm going through section 8.2 Michael Hartl's RoR 3.2 tutorial and can't seem to get a user signed in.  I've followed the tutorial exactly, but for some reason @current_user appears to be blank when I debug and print it out on a view after submitting the sign in form.  I've looked over the code multiple times and can't seem to find anything wrong.  Any help appreciated.  Thank you.

```
module SessionsHelper

    def sign_in(user)
        cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
        self.current_user = user
    end

    def signed_in?
        !current_user.nil?  
    end

    def current_user=(user)
        @current_user = user
    end

    def current_user
        @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
    end

    def sign_out
        self.current_user = nil
        cookies.delete(:remember_token)
    end
end
```

My sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

def new
end

def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        sign_in user 
        redirect_to new_job_url
    else
        flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
        render 'new'
    end
end

def destroy
  sign_out
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

end

Comment: Why do you have an = sign on your def current_user(user) statement?

Comment: Per the tutorial: [http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out.html#code-current_user_working]

Comment: Are all of your tests passing?  If not, what error is being given?  Also, what is `new_job_url`, as I don't think I've seen that in the tutorial.